# Erro apos View ser chamada

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

Possuo uma tela de login com a seguinte chamada quando o usuario clicka no botao "entrar"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#formLogin").on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var mensagem = "Dados de Login inválidos.";
        var button = $('#btnEntrar');

        button.html("Validando...").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        if ($('#username').val() != "" && $('#password').val() != "") {
          $.ajax({
              url: '/Admin/Login',
              type: "POST",
              data: form.serialize(),
              success: function (resp) {
                $('#lblMsgAutenticacao').fadeOut(400);
                window.location = '/Admin/Inscricoes';
              },
              error: function (req, status, errorObj) {
                $('#lblMsgAutenticacao').html(mensagem).fadeIn(400);
                button.html("Entrar").removeAttr("disabled");
              },
              complete: function() {

                setTimeout(function(){
                  $('#lblMsgAutenticacao').fadeOut(400);
                }, 3000)
              }
          });
        }
        else {
          $('#lblMsgAutenticacao').fadeIn(400);
          button.html("Entrar").removeAttr("disabled");
        }

        if ($('#username').val() == "")
          $('#username').focus();
        else
          $('#password').focus();
    });
  });
```

essa chamada leva ao metodo abaixo:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
{
    Usuario usuario = null;
    try
    {
       usuario = LoginBll.Valida(username, password);
       if (usuario == null )
          throw new Exception();
       else 
          Session["loginAdm"] = usuario;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
          throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
    }
        return RedirectToAction("Inscricoes");    
   }
```

que por sua vez leva ao metodo:

```
 public ActionResult Inscricoes()
        {
            inscricoes_model.ViewModel.AdmInscricao admInscricao = null;
            try
            {
                admInscricao = new inscricoes_model.ViewModel.AdmInscricao();
                admInscricao.instituicoes = InstituicaoBll.Listar(null);
                return View(admInscricao);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception(e.Message, e);
            }

        }
```

tudo roda corretamente sem nenhum erro a view é chamada sem nenhum erro no codigo porem o retorno da funçao ajax é sempre erro e nao redireciona para a pagina correta. não consigo identificar onde está esse erro, diz apenas "Internal Server Error", alguma ideia de por onde posso começar ?

Comment: tenta chamar direto no navegador o endereço http://localhost:porta//Admin/Login?username=aaa&password=123
Só acho que terás que mudar o seu método login para HttpGet antes. OBS: coloca um usuário e senha válidos na sua chamada.

Comment: Cara ajudou bastante, usei a url completa para a pagina que o method redireciona e encontrei alguns erros nela que pude corrigir, obrigado.

Comment: Adiciona sua solução para vermos o que foi feito.

Comment: Você chegou a modificar para HttpGet o método login?

Comment: não, com o post mesmo funcionou, o problema é que em uma partialView que tinha na pagina ele tentava usar um objeto que foi removido do sistema, quando retirei essa parte da partialView funcionou, so achei estranho que nao aparecia o erro antes e compilava direto o programa sem erro. mas o que alterei foi o seguinte na partial view.

@{
    if (Session["loginAdm"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect(Url.Action("Index", "Admin"));
    }
    inscricoes_model.Login login = (inscricoes_model.Login)Session["loginAdm"]; <---- esse objeto nao existe mais no sistema, foi soh retirar ele
}

Answer (score 1):

Uma técnica que uso para descobrir erros de chamadas via ajax, é simular a chamada direto pelo navegador web a *action* em questão.

No seu caso, você poderia fazer a requisição a seguinte URL  http://localhost:porta//Admin/Login?username=aaa&password=123 passando um usuário e senha válidos do seu sistema.